# PHP download a file through direct link and save it on my server

Tags: php, linux, download

I'm trying to run PHP script (from a Linux server) that will download a file through direct download link and save it on my server.

here is the script I'm using:

```
<?php

    $url  = 'http://download.maxmind.com/app/geoip_download?edition_id=108&date=20131015&suffix=zip&license_key=XXXXXXXXXXX';
    $path = '/apps/test/';

    $fp = fopen($path, 'w');

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

for some reason it doesn't work for me, any suggestions ?

Comment: Which is the output file name ?

Comment: Have you checked the logs? Do you (php/apache user) have the permission to write to that directory?

Comment: The file name is GeoIP-YYYYMMDD.zip, I don't want to rename it but to save it as it is under /apps/test/, and YES I do have the write permission to the specified folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to verify that the ports are open on your firewall and use the below command:
(this will also download the file in the original format)

```
shell_exec("wget -P /apps/birst/php_test_scripts/ --content-disposition "."'"."https://download.maxmind.com/app/geoip_download?edition_id=108&suffix=zip&license_key=XXXXXXXX"."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just use :

```
shell_exec("wget -P /target/directory/ http://download.link.com/download.zip");
```

Comment: well, I assume it should work but I get Connection refused:              Resolving download.maxmind.com... 108.168.255.243, 2607:f0d0:3:8::4
Connecting to download.maxmind.com|108.168.255.243|:80... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to download.maxmind.com|2607:f0d0:3:8::4|:80... failed: Address family not supported by protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$url = 'http://download.maxmind.com/app/geoip_download?edition_id=108&date=20131015&suffix=zip&license_key=XXXXXXXXXXX';
$path = '/apps/test/';
$filepath = $path .'file.zip';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents($filepath, $data);
```